# Play! Request charset

Tags: character-encoding, playframework

I'm converting a Servlet into a Play! Controller but I can't find the Play! equivalent of

```
HttpServletRequest request;
String charset = request.getCharacterEncoding();
```

A helping hand needed over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
request.headers.get("Content-Type").value()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I'm doing. First going for the  Content-type header and if it's not present there, try the Accept-Charset.